# I can not able to access all URL using CURL

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am using curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL

I can able to access the website like google

```
curl https://google.com
```

But, when I am accessing a website like python website

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
```

curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.22.218.218 port 8085: Timed out

But, I can able to accesss from browser

Comment: can you share the curl -v output?

Comment: Oh. Thanks for responding. I just checked now. 2nd command ls working. Maybe I should delete the question

Comment: curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL